# Cannot map agent.conf using Cygnus docker installation

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I have problem installing CYGNUS using docker as source, simply i cannot understand where i should map what specific agent.conf.

Image i am using is from [here.](https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/cygnus-ngsi/)

When i try to map agent.conf witch have my specific setup to container it starts and run but fail to copy, and not only that any change i made to file inside container wont stay it returns to previous default state.

While i have no issues with grouping_rules.conf using same approach.

I used docker and docker compose both same results.
Path on witch i try to copy opt/apache-flume/conf/agent.conf

```
docker run -v /home/igor/Documents/cygnus/agent.conf:/opt/apache-flume/conf/agent.conf fiware/cygnus-ngsi
```

Can some who managed to run it using his config tell me if i misunderstood location of agent.conf or something because this is weird, i used many docker images and never had issue where i was not able to copy from my machine to docker container.

Thanks in advance.

** EDIT **

[Link of agent.conf](https://www95.zippyshare.com/v/serQtk5r/file.html)

Comment: Could you provide the following info: (1) The error that is giving you (2) version of components that you are using and perhaps (3) the agent.conf? Thanks!

Comment: 1. No error, container runs fine but wont change default agent.config, try with volumes -v mapping and direct changes to container. Version in use: {"success":"true","version":"1.9.0_SNAPSHOT.d492237ae17c2a4df30c3633148f261a2cef1fd6"}

Comment: Another option that you have is adapt the docker file to your needs and build your own image.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy the **agent.conf** file to your directory before start the container?

As you can see [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/17470), when you define a volume with "-v" option, docker copies the content of the host directory, inside the container directory using the mount point. Therefore, you must first provide the agent.conf file on your host.

> The reason is that when using a "bind mounted" directory from the
>   host, you're telling docker that you want to take a file or directory
>   from your host and use it in your container. Docker should not modify
>   those files/directories, unless you explicitly do so. For example, you
>   don't want -v /home/user/:/var/lib/mysql to result in your
>   home-directory being replaced with a MySQL database.

If you do not have access to the agent.conf file, you can download the template in the source code from the official cygnus github repo [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/cygnus-ngsi/conf/agent_ngsi.conf.template). You can also copy it once the docker container is running, using the [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#description) option:

```
docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target
```

Keep in mind, that you will have to edit the agent.conf file to configure it according to the database you are using. You can find in the official [doc](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/1.3.0/index.html) how to configure cygnus to use differents sinks like MongoDB, MySQL, etc.

I hope I have been helpful.

Best regards!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but simply not working. This could be easily not cygnus fault but mine way of implementing it. So if u manage to run cygnus using docker i have few questions. First where did u copy agent.conf, did u use cygnus_instance.conf, and what docker image did u use to run it. I want to see what i missed here.